# MomentOfInertia help

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, regions

Radius and angle must be assigned in order to get the result. When radius and angle are variables, how to get the result?

```
Clear["Global`*"];
body = ParametricRegion[{r*Cos[θ], 
    r*Sin[θ]}, {{θ, -α, α}}];
ℐ = 
 MomentOfInertia[body, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, 
  Assumptions -> r > 0 && Pi > α > 0]

(* Returns unevaluated *)
```

Or,

```
Clear["Global`*"];
body = Circle[{0, 0}, r, {-α, α}];
ℐ = 
 MomentOfInertia[body, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, 
  Assumptions -> r > 0 && Pi > α > 0]

(* Returns unevaluated *)

Clear["Global`*"];
body = ParametricRegion[{2*Cos[θ], 
    2*Sin[θ]}, {{θ, -Pi/6, Pi/6}}];
ℐ = MomentOfInertia[body, {0, 0}, {1, 0}]

(*2/3 (-3 Sqrt[3] + 2 π)*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
bod[r_, α_] := ParametricRegion[{r*Cos[θ],r*Sin[θ]}, {{θ, -α, α}}];
MomentOfInertia[bod[r, α]]// Simplify[#, r > 0] &
(*{{r^3 (α - Cos[α] Sin[α]), 0}, {0, (r^3 (-1 + α^2 + Cos[2 α] + α Cos[α] \Sin[α]))/α}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: @lotus2019 You're welcome!

Comment: @lotus2019 …Well, but I think this isn't an answer to your question?

Comment: @xzczd The rotation axis needs to be set. bod[r_, \[Alpha]_] := 
  ParametricRegion[{r*Cos[\[Theta]], 
    r*Sin[\[Theta]]}, {{\[Theta], -\[Alpha], \[Alpha]}}];
MomentOfInertia[bod[r, \[Alpha]], {0, 0}, {1, 0}] // 
 Simplify[#, r > 0] &

Comment: @xzczd My answer gives all components of the inertiatensor.

Answer (score 1):

It's funny that, if we take away the `Assumptions` option, then the first sample works:

```
body = 
  ParametricRegion[{r*Cos[θ], r*Sin[θ]}, {{θ, -α, α}}];
ℐ = MomentOfInertia[body, {0, 0}, {1, 0}]
(* (r^2)^(3/2) (α - Cos[α] Sin[α]) *)
```

Tested in *v12.3.1* and *v13.0.0*. I suggest reporting it to WRI.

BTW, though `MomentOfInertia` cannot handle the `Circle[…]` directly, we can use `RegionConvert` the `Circle[…]` to a `ParametricRegion`:

```
body2 = RegionConvert[Circle[{0, 0}, r, {-α, α}], "Parametric"]
(* ParametricRegion[{{r Cos[\[FormalX]], 
   r Sin[\[FormalX]]}, -α <= \[FormalX] <= α}, {\[FormalX]}] *)

ℐ = MomentOfInertia[body2, {0, 0}, {1, 0}]
(* (r^2)^(3/2) (α - Cos[α] Sin[α]) *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!